# Share branches directly between computers (without making them public)

Tags: git, workflow, branch

I have a public repo(origin) with a branch (master). I've created a new branch to test a few libraries that a colleague and I intend to use. What I'd like to do is share this branch with my colleague without unnecessarily creating it in the origin remote.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I thought about defining our computers as remote, but I don't really have a clear idea on how to do it.

Comment: Yes of course you can do this. Git is a distributed version control system (DVCS). Every machine has its own local database and most of the commands are executed locally. All you need is to let your friends know your IP address and they can clone/fetch (and do whatever they do with a remote repo) using ssh for example. They can add your repo as a remote with `git remote add <name> <url>` then they can start fetching, pulling and pushing to your repo.

Comment: Thanks, that I understand! I'm not sure what the url would be, something like mydomain/path/to/rootDir ?

Comment: the url would be something like: `username@yourIP:/path/to/git`

Comment: I tried git remote add username@ip:~/git/intranet2 (this is the directory where I've got .git) but it didnt work. What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing the .git part. For example: `~/git/intranet2/.git`.

Comment: mmm no, it didn't work. I tried to add the remote and then checkout -b newbranch repo/branch but it says 'Did you intend to checkout 'cbiscussi/gulp' which can not be resolved as commit?'

Comment: Maybe you didn't fetch before checking out? Try this after adding the remote (make sure you have an initial commit): `git fetch repo` then `git checkout -b newbranch repo/branch`.

Comment: that was it! I hadn't fetched! Thanks a lot! shame I can't mark a comment as an answer

Comment: Great! I'll post an answer collecting the comments and you mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is collected from the comments on the original post.

Yes of course you can do this. Git is a distributed version control system (DVCS). Every machine has its own local database and most of the commands are executed locally. All you need is to let your friends know your IP address and they can clone/fetch (and do whatever they do with a remote repo) using ssh for example. They can add your repo as a remote with `git remote add <name> <url>` then they can start fetching, pulling and pushing to your repo.

the url would be something like: `username@yourIP:/path/to/git/.git`

Don't forget to fetch before creating a branch.